# BUILD : Jasmine-maven-plugin error

Tags: java, maven, build, neo4j

While trying to build neo4j from source, i'm getting following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.2.0.0:te
st (webadmin-specs) on project neo4j-server: There were Jasmine spec failures. -
> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

This error occurs while i try to build "Server" component of neo4j.

Any inputs will be of great help

More Stack trace:
More stack trace....                                                [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.2.0.0:test (webadmin-specs) on project neo4j-server: There were Jasmine spec failures. -

> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.2.0.0:test (webadmin-specs) on project n
>   eo4j-server: There were Jasmine spec failures.
>          at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

Comment: this is stalling my progress any input will be of great great help

Answer (score 1):

I also got same error.
It was due to Test failure. There was a problem with one of javascript file in that project. I solved the problem and it start working fine.

Hope this will help.